# Pandas - getting weekly transform of datetime column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

- Is there a way of doing a groupby(freq=W) on a Datetime column and get the resulting freq date as a new column?
- How would I go about shifting the resulting "current_week" by 1 week?
- Is there an easy way to to change the groupby(freq="M") and also get the 1 Month offset?
- I need to do this to merge the offsetting date with weekly dataset, but stuck on how best to approach this

  ```
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({0: datetime.date(2019, 2, 1), 1: datetime.date(2019, 2, 4), 2: datetime.date(2019, 2, 5),
                       3: datetime.date(2019, 2, 6), 4: datetime.date(2019, 2, 7), 5: datetime.date(2019, 2, 8),
                       6: datetime.date(2019, 2, 11), 7: datetime.date(2019, 2, 12), 8: datetime.date(2019, 2, 13),
                       9: datetime.date(2019, 2, 14), 10: datetime.date(2019, 2, 15), 11: datetime.date(2019, 2, 18),
                       12: datetime.date(2019, 2, 19), 13: datetime.date(2019, 2, 20), 14: datetime.date(2019, 2, 21),
                       15: datetime.date(2019, 2, 22), 16: datetime.date(2019, 2, 25), 17: datetime.date(2019, 2, 26),
                       18: datetime.date(2019, 2, 27), 19: datetime.date(2019, 2, 28)}, index=['daily']
                      ).T
    print(df)
  ```

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** `datetime.date` does not play well with earlier Pandas version. I would make the date Pandas' datetime type:

```
df['daily'] = pd.to_datetime(df['daily'])
```

In you case, try:

```
df['offset_by_1week'] = df.daily.dt.to_period('W-SAT').dt.to_timestamp()
```

You can replace `'W-SAT'` with `'M'` for month and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with some of the lesser used `GroupBy` attributes. First make your dates `datetime` that way you can do operations in pandas. Then we grab the `BinGrouper` object created by the grouper allowing us to map rows to their label.

Then you can add/subtract a week with `pd.offsets.DateOffset`

```
df['daily'] = pd.to_datetime(df['daily'])
gp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='daily', freq='W')).grouper

df['current_week'] = (pd.Series(gp.codes_info, index=df.index)
                        .map(dict(zip(gp.codes[0], gp.levels[0]))))

df['next_week'] = df['current_week'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(weeks=1)
```

---

```
        daily current_week  next_week
0  2019-02-01   2019-02-03 2019-01-27
1  2019-02-04   2019-02-10 2019-02-03
2  2019-02-05   2019-02-10 2019-02-03
3  2019-02-06   2019-02-10 2019-02-03
4  2019-02-07   2019-02-10 2019-02-03
5  2019-02-08   2019-02-10 2019-02-03
....
17 2019-02-26   2019-03-03 2019-02-24
18 2019-02-27   2019-03-03 2019-02-24
19 2019-02-28   2019-03-03 2019-02-24
```